# convert data type of any to float in matrix in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a matrix(rand2) of type "any", and I want to convert the type to float. I have following code.

```
for i in 1:size(rand2,1)
   rand2[i,:]=convert(Array{Float64,1}, rand2[i,:])
end
```

Such code will not change the data type. What‘s the issue here?

Answer (score 6):

Use [dot operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators) to vectorize over type conversion.

Suppose you have

```
julia> m = Matrix{Any}(rand(2,2))
2×2 Matrix{Any}:
 0.250737  0.0366769
 0.240182  0.883665
```

Than you could do

```
julia> Float64.(m)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.250737  0.0366769
 0.240182  0.883665
```

or you could explicitly call vectorized `convert`:

```
julia> convert.(Float64, m)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.250737  0.0366769
 0.240182  0.883665
```

Answer (score 6):

Julia arrays, once created, cannot have their type changed; this is necessary for high performance. So, trying to change the type midway as you have tried won't work. You have to create a new array similar to the original one but with the new type.

You could do this:

```
m64 = similar(m, Float64)
m64 .= m
```

This will be 10X faster than direct conversion like `Float64.(m)`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to *Przemyslaw Szufel*'s answer, you can use the `identity` function, which narrows the element type of your matrix. Example:

```
# I use the example of Przemyslaw Szufel
julia> m = Matrix{Any}(rand(2,2))
2×2 Matrix{Any}:
 0.250737  0.0366769
 0.240182  0.883665

julia> identity.(m)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.250737  0.0366769
 0.240182  0.883665
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this is 2X as fast as the solutions in Przemyslaw's answer - not sure what's making `convert` so slow.  AboAmmar's suggestion is still ~5X faster than this. But this may be  a one time conversion where minor performance differences don't change much, and with `identity` you get the guarantee that Julia chooses the most suitable data type *for* you based on the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Matrix` to convert to `Float64`.

```
m = Matrix{Any}([1. 2.; 3. 4.])
#2×2 Matrix{Any}:
# 1.0  2.0
# 3.0  4.0

Matrix{Float64}(m)
#Array{Float64}(m) #Alternative
#2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
# 1.0  2.0
# 3.0  4.0
```

Also it's possible to use `convert` as shown already by [@przemyslaw-szufel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73548643/10488504) but without `.`.

```
convert(Matrix{Float64}, m)
#convert(Array{Float64}, m) #Alternative
#2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
# 1.0  2.0
# 3.0  4.0
```

The conversion by using `similar` shown by [@AboAmmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549415/10488504) need not to be done over an intermediate step.

```
similar(m, Float64) .= m
#2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
# 1.0  2.0
# 3.0  4.0
```

---

Benchmark

```
using BenchmarkTools

m = Matrix{Any}(rand(1000,1000))

@benchmark Float64.($m)
#BenchmarkTools.Trial: 32 samples with 1 evaluation.
# Range (min … max):  156.779 ms … 170.114 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
# Time  (median):     159.612 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
# Time  (mean ± σ):   161.097 ms ±   4.111 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.03% ± 0.07%
#
#  ▁ ▁   ▁▁ ▁  ▄ █                                                
#  █▁█▆▁▆██▁█▆▁█▆█▆▆▁▆▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▆▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▆▁▁▆▁▆▁▆▆▁▁▆▁▁▁▆ ▁
#  157 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          170 ms <
#
# Memory estimate: 7.63 MiB, allocs estimate: 2.

@benchmark convert.(Float64, $m)
#BenchmarkTools.Trial: 30 samples with 1 evaluation.
# Range (min … max):  168.258 ms … 177.510 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
# Time  (median):     170.444 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
# Time  (mean ± σ):   170.794 ms ±   1.996 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.05% ± 0.12%
#
#       █ ██     ▃      ▃  ▃                                      
#  ▇▁▇▇▁█▁██▁▁▇▁▇█▁▇▇▁▇▇█▇▇█▁▇▁▁▁▇▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▇▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▇ ▁
#  168 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          178 ms <
#
# Memory estimate: 7.63 MiB, allocs estimate: 13.

@benchmark identity.($m)
#BenchmarkTools.Trial: 58 samples with 1 evaluation.
# Range (min … max):  84.857 ms … 91.658 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
# Time  (median):     85.980 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
# Time  (mean ± σ):   86.873 ms ±  2.009 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.10% ± 0.24%
#
#  █    ▃▁▆  ▁    ▁                                             
#  █▄▇▇▄███▇▄█▇▁▄▁█▇▄▁▁▁▄▁▄▁▁▄▄▁▁▁▇▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄▁▁▁▄▇▁▇▄▁▇▄▁▁▄▄ ▁
#  84.9 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        90.9 ms <
#
# Memory estimate: 7.63 MiB, allocs estimate: 12.

@benchmark begin
    m64 = similar($m, Float64)
    m64 .= $m
end
#BenchmarkTools.Trial: 289 samples with 1 evaluation.
# Range (min … max):  15.963 ms …  21.972 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 3.92%
# Time  (median):     17.319 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
# Time  (mean ± σ):   17.332 ms ± 878.046 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.79% ± 2.83%
#
#   ▄ ▁ ▅                ▁▃▂▅▄█▂▂▁                               
#  ▇███▆██▃▃▄▃▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄▄▇█████████▇▅▄▄▆▃▃▁▆▄▅▆▅██▇▄█▄▄▅▄▄▄▁▃▄▃▃ ▄
#  16 ms           Histogram: frequency by time           19 ms <
#
# Memory estimate: 22.88 MiB, allocs estimate: 999491.

@benchmark similar($m, Float64) .= $m
#BenchmarkTools.Trial: 299 samples with 1 evaluation.
# Range (min … max):  16.108 ms …  21.211 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% #… 0.00%
# Time  (median):     16.795 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
# Time  (mean ± σ):   16.740 ms ± 500.870 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  1.81% #± 1.82%
#
#        ▂▃▄▆ ▃▁                   ▄▃ █                          
#  ▃▃▁▃▄█████▇██▅▇▄▆▆▆▃▅▃▃▁▅▃▄▃█▆████▅██▆█▆▅▆▅▅▃▃▃▄▃▃▁▃▁▄▁▁▁▁▁▃ ▃
#  16.1 ms         Histogram: frequency by time         17.6 ms <
#
# Memory estimate: 22.88 MiB, allocs estimate: 999491.

@benchmark Matrix{Float64}($m)
#BenchmarkTools.Trial: 282 samples with 1 evaluation.
# Range (min … max):  16.243 ms … 23.092 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 7.39%
# Time  (median):     18.299 ms              ┊ GC (median):    4.62%
# Time  (mean ± σ):   17.745 ms ±  1.196 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  5.71% ± 5.45%
#
#    ▃▆▆█▂                                 ▃▄                   
#  ▃██████▄▆▃▄▄▅▁▃▃▄▃▃▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▃▄▅▆▇█▇███▇▇▇▆▆▃▃▃▃▁▃▁▄▃▃▁▃ ▃
#  16.2 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        19.9 ms <
#
# Memory estimate: 22.88 MiB, allocs estimate: 999491.

@benchmark convert(Matrix{Float64}, $m)
#BenchmarkTools.Trial: 301 samples with 1 evaluation.
# Range (min … max):  15.912 ms …  21.628 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% #… 0.00%
# Time  (median):     16.719 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
# Time  (mean ± σ):   16.622 ms ± 576.159 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.43% #± 2.45%
#
#         ▆█                    ▁  ▃                             
#  ▂▁▂▄▅▄███▇▅▅▇▃▂▃▃▆▃▁▂▂▁▁▂▃▅▇▇█▇▅██▅▆▅▄▄▃▃▃▃▂▂▂▃▂▁▂▁▂▁▂▂▁▁▁▁▃ ▃
#  15.9 ms         Histogram: frequency by time         17.7 ms <
#
# Memory estimate: 22.88 MiB, allocs estimate: 999491.
```

Using `similar`, `Matrix` or `convert` are in this case about 5 times faster than using `identity.` and 10 times faster than `convert.` or `Float64.`. But they aren't memory efficient as `identity.`, `convert.` and `Float64.` are and using in this case about 3 times more memory.

Comment: But they aren't memory efficient as `identity.`, `convert.`, and `Float64.` are.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the formulation and added your sentence.